# Using Saga with redux with Typescript on react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm a newbie with Type script, I tried to create redux with saga, I create the actions that normally worked and saga file it works too but when I try to get the data from the request I Got a type error, even when I pass the whole result to reducer I couldn't get to the data on the request,
here the code :

```
// actions file 
export const getUsersRequest = () => {
 return {
   type: ActionType.GET_USERS_REQUEST
 }
}

export const getUsersSuccess = (users : any) => {
  return  {
      type : ActionType.GET_USERS_SUCCESS,
     payload:  users
  }
}
export const getUsersFailed = (error: any) => {
 
  return   {
      type:  ActionType.GET_USERS_FAILED ,
       payload: error
     }
  
}
```

saga file

```
 import {call, put, takeLatest} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as actions from '../action-creator/index';
import {ActionType} from '../types/index'
import * as api from '../api/users';

function* getUsers () : Generator {
try {
    let  result = yield call(api.getUsers) 
    console.log("saga data" ,result)
    yield put(actions.getUsersSuccess(result))
}catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}
}

export function* usersSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(ActionType.GET_USERS_REQUEST, getUsers )
}
```

reducer file

```
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { ActionType} from '../types'

const INITIAL_STATE ={ 
  users :  []
};

const reducer =(state  =  INITIAL_STATE, action: AnyAction  ) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case ActionType.GET_USERS_SUCCESS : 
    let users  = action.payload.users 
    return {
      ...state, 
      users: users
    }
    
    
    default :
      return state
    }
}

export default reducer
```

The issue here is I cant get access to  users list on data of the request,
Thank you

Comment: Did you add the `usersSaga` to the saga middleware as your root saga or did you make sure it's included in your root saga?

Comment: Also what is the return shape/value of `api.getUsers`

Comment: Please explain the error that you are getting.  Edit your post to include the whole error stack trace.  “I get an error” is not enough information for us to give helpful advice.